# Component ngOninit model bind issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

Component `profile.component.ts` is a **child component** and is trying to bind a dummy model which is shown below.

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() {
}
objName: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAsyncData().subscribe(j => {          
      this.objName = j.FirstName;
    });
}

getAsyncData() {
    // Fake Slow Async Data
    return of({
      FirstName: 'Luke',
      LastName: 'Skywalker'
    }).pipe(delay(2000));
  }

}
```

Here is my HTML page below.

```
<div class="col-12 col-form-label mb-5">
      {{objName | async}}
</div>
```

Now this `this.objName = j.FirstName;` gets data but does not bind on HTML page whether I use **async** or not on HTML page.

**Update 1**:
Browser error without `async`.
[image: browser error]

Comment: Do you have any error in your browser's console when not using the async pipe?
since you subscribe manually to the observable, you don't need it

Comment: @LielFridman nothing related to that I've updated the question

Comment: I can't replicate your problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-violet-cjmnkp?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The code you provided works fine without the `async` pipe https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eptpjo?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Your issue probably has to do with the four unrelated errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `| async` pipe it will only work on an Observable.

In your case `this.objName` is not an observable. `this.objName` is a value from property `Firstname` on object `j` which was emitted. You are trying to treat a single value as an observable - that's not how this works. Follow my example for better understanding on this.

Also try to use camelCase instead of PascalCase when naming properties (e.g `FirstName` to `firstName`).

```html
<div>
  {{ objName$ | async }}
  <br />
  <br />
  <ng-container *ngIf="objName$ | async as obj">
    {{ obj.FirstName }}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'async-pipe',
  templateUrl: './async-pipe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./async-pipe.component.css'],
})
export class AsyncPipeComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  objName$: Observable<any>;
  unsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.objName$ = this.getAsyncData().pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$));
  }

  getAsyncData() {
    // Fake Slow Async Data
    return of({
      FirstName: 'Luke',
      LastName: 'Skywalker',
    }).pipe(delay(2000));
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/async-pipe-8c2brn?file=app%2Fasync-pipe%2Fasync-pipe.component.ts