# async template bind from subscribe angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables, angular13

I'm trying to bind data on **subscribe** on **ngOninit**, here is the page **profile.component.ts** below.

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  public userDetailsArr: UserDetails[] = [];
  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

 async ngOnInit() {
    await this.userManagementService.currentUsersIdValue
      .subscribe(async (userId: number) => {
        const user = await this.userManagementService.getUsers(userId.toString())
          .subscribe(x => {
            this.userDetailsArr = x;
            console.log(this.userDetailsArr); // data shows here
          });
        this.subscriptions.push(user);
      });

  console.log(this.userDetailsArr); // data does not show here
}

}
```

Here is the HTML template page **profile.component.html** shown below.

```
<form>
    <div>
      <ng-container *ngIf="userDetailsArr as obj">
        {{ obj.firstName }} //does not show data
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" [(ngModel)]="userDetails.FirstName" /> //does not bind model
</form>
```

Data comes in this format.

```
[{
  id: 9, addressID: 0, firstName: 'Dang', lastName: 'Kumar'
}]
```

I get data in JSON successfully but,

1. It receives in **camelCase** but my model is of **PascalCase**
2. It does not bind data on `{{ obj.firstName }}` or `[(ngModel)]="userDetails.FirstName"` as the latter is of Pascal I understand and incoming JSON is of Camel.
3. Even though i pass within Subscribe `userDetails.FirstName = "test"` it still won't bind on `[(ngModel)]="userDetails.FirstName"`.

Comment: your `userDetailsArr` is an array. you're accessing it as though it's an object. and angular can't figure out your pascal to camel mappings for you, you need to do the mappings yourself

Comment: @bryan60 even if I do `<li *ngFor="let obj of userDetailsArr; index as i">
            {{ obj.firstName }}
          </li>`  this won't bind data on template, it maps data within subscribe but convert it to camel from Pascal

Comment: No disrespect meant, but you might want to follow some tutorials on Angular, typescript and Observables.

Comment: @MikeOne thank you for the advice but how do you check change detection on page load when subscription is done on `ngOninit`. That is what is now not working

Comment: What are you doing with userDetails? Is doesn't seem to have any relationship with the subscribes (why all the awaits? These are not Promises right..?). If you do it correctly (whatever you're trying to do) - you won't have any issues with change detection ;-) - The whole camel- versus Pascal casing is also confusing - there is no magic casting or anything here? In short - you'll need to go back to the basics - which also means understanding RxJs (and the differences with Promises) and what exactly Typescript is. Again - no disrespect but you seem to want to run before you can walk.

Comment: @MikeOne found the issue as `this.userManagementService.currentUsersIdValue` was using `subject` changed that to `BehaviourSubject` and it all started to work, will add the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my service page I was using. `private currentUserId = new Subject<string>();`
Here is the code which was being used below.

```
  private currentUserId = new Subject<string>();
  public get currentUsersIdValue() {
    return this.currentUserId;
  }
  public set currentUsersIdValue(value) {
    this.currentUserId = value;
  }
```

Now the issue was the `new Subject<string>()` which I changed it to `new BehaviorSubject<string>('')`, this worked perfectly. During subscribe `subject` would not work only `BehaviorSubject` would.

Answer (score -1):

U should mark component as dirty with `changeDetector.markForCheck()` if u don't use async pipe. Also dont use nested subscriptions, I fixed this with `switchMap()`

```
const userSubscription = this.userManagementService.currentUsersIdValue.pipe(
   switchMap((userId) => this.userManagementService.getUsers(userId.toString())),
).subscribe((users) => {
  this.userDetailsArr = users;
  this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
});
this.subscriptions.push(userSubscription);
```

Comment: Added the code you made and added it like this `constructor(private router: Router,
    private userManagementService: UserManagementService,
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
  }` with calling it as `this.ref.markForCheck();` didn't work though

Comment: How u wanna get `{{ obj.firstName }}` if `obj` is an array

Comment: well model is coming in camel case which is being bind on. So first I need to see the data shown on the template this is a child component but as I see this has nothing to do with it. Problem is its not binding at all I've done every possible way to do that, there is reference I made it checks with a timer here is reference, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71702920/10668235 this works but not the way I want it in subscription.